# How to multiply Cloud Functions timeout time?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I know that Firebase/Google Cloud Functions can have timeout [increased up to 9 minutes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation), but I have a Pub/Sub function that one request within it needs around 20-30 seconds to complete (document conversion).

```js
async function () {
   // code...
   // const convertedDoc = await convertDocument()
   // ... do something with convertedDoc
}
```

With 9 minutes of maximum timeout it gives me up to 18 documents I can process.

My question is if after 15th document conversion I would call PubSub function again while finishing the previous invocation will timeout timer start over with new function? Of course, I would need to pass all the data from previous one, but is that a way to do it? Something like recursive PubSub of sorts?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind, I would suggest a slightly different approach.

Let's divide the whole process into 2 steps.

The first step - a cloud function which "collects" all documents (I mean their id, or reference, or metadata to uniquely distinct one from others) into a list, and then sends a message per document into a PubSub topic. That message contains a unique identifier/handle/hash of the document, so it can be fetch/processed later.

The PubSub topic triggers (push) the second cloud function. This cloud function is deployed with a maximum instances argument of a few dozens (or hundreds) depending on the context and requirements. Thus, many cloud function instances are being executed parallel, but each cloud function instance is triggered by a message with a unique document id.

The cloud function performs the processing you described, and presumably it takes 20 or 30 seconds. As many cloud functions are being executed in parallel, the overall processing time can be less, than if everything is done sequentially.

In addition, you might like to keep the state of a process in a firestore database using a document id as a firestore record id. Thus each record reflects a process of handling of one particular document. By doing that, any possible duplication can be eliminated, and a self-healing process can be organised.

Comment: That's a very interesting idea. Looks like [Firebase/Google Cloud Functions limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas) max concurrent invocations to 1000 so I would probably need to get a number of how many documents will be converted and then divide it by thousand (if there are more documents than that - below that it's redundant). The extra step I need to take into consideration is zipping files up - I would need to orchestrate it somehow because it's one zip that has all the files (I know, didn't said that before).

Comment: You made me think - I will get back here with updated question after I will think of a potential solution.